# Building Multiple Solutions Targeting Different .Net Core Version In Travis

Tags: .net-core, travis-ci

I have two .Net Core solutions in my repository, one targeting .Net Core 2.2 and the other .Net Core 3.
I want Travis to build both of these Solutions, but I can only specify one version in the .travis.yml, Thus the the other project fails to build.

My .travis.yml:

```
dist: xenial 
language: csharp
mono: none
dotnet: 2.2
script:
  #Build Major Application
  - dotnet restore NetCore22Solution/NetCore22Solution.sln
  - dotnet build NetCore22Solution/NetCore22Solution.sln

  #Build Services
  - dotnet restore NetCore3Solution/NetCore3Solution.sln
  - dotnet build NetCore3Solution/NetCore3Solution.sln
```

How do I specify I also need .Net Core 3?

I searched travis's c# forum, github issues and obviously google, but didn't find any solution.

Comment: Did you find something related? Im facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the required version as a package and it worked:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - dotnet-sdk-3.0
```

Travis honestly downloaded and installed SDK.